# Fixed header breaks visibility

Tags: css

When we put a header with fixed position, why the visibility is broken ?

see http://jsfiddle.net/YLx5S/

i just put

```
position: fixed; width: 100%;
```

at the div

how to correct that and display a scroll bar ? the nav is partially hidden.

Comment: Do you mean the padding on the left side? Or that something overlaps it? To remove the padding, you just need to remove the padding from the body. If you are having issue that header isn't above all other content, you will need to give it a high enough `z-index`. Last; if you mean the content flowing out of the window; then you need to control the `div`'s `overflow`.

Comment: No, i mean that i can't scroll to see the rest of nav for example. there is no scroll bar automatically proposed

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. Do you mean that you want a scrollbar to appear within the header?

Comment: its positioned fixed, it can''t scroll.  Even if you did have a scroll bar there, the nav would stay in its position and scroll with it.  If this is really what you'll need, you're best bet is to implement a js solution combined with position absolute.

Comment: not only css solution ? :(

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow scroll:

```
nav{
    width:500px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: this is ugly :( i want a "normal" scrollbar at bottom of the page

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you want. Could you draw it for me or try to explain better what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am not sure if i understand you question correctly but here is what i did.  I removed the position:fixed from the nav and added a main container at the top level.   Here is the js fiddle take a look <http://jsfiddle.net/jspatel/9zmNR/>

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hzLNm/

You could float them left.

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: this is not the problem, i mean the "horizontal visibility" of nav's content